# can a windows computer have a mac user agent?

Tags: user-agent

I tried to search for this but I didn't find anything (which could simply be because I'm not sure what terms to use to search), so I hope this doesn't annoy anyone!

I have an IP tracker on my blog and I'm trying to figure out the identity of a regular visitor (within reason, of course! I know that information can't tell you a lot!). I'm *rather* confident of who it is based on various non-IP related clues, but the one thing that throws me off is that it shows the person as having a user agent that is apparently associated with Macs.

This is the user agent in question: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/536.28.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.3 Safari/536.28.10

Now, I'm not psychic or anything, haha, but I'm pretty sure the person I *thought* it was does not have a Mac OS X. So I was wondering how reliable user agents are for determining the operating system and if it is possible for a Windows OS to have a Mac user agent WITHOUT the person manually going in to change their own user agent or installing a plugin. If not, I guess I was wrong about who it was, lol!

Thank you for your help and, again, I'm sorry if this is a really obvious question; I really did try my best to search!

Comment: The user-agent is something the browser supplies and is not something that is guaranteed to be true (for Firefox there are even add-ons to switch the user-agent to anything you want). Btw: in Europe (or to be more precise: in the EU) it is not allowed to store the IP addresses of your visitors so you should check with a lawyer if your IP tracker is actually legal.

Comment: Why is storing an ip not legal over here (when notifying the end user about this fact)? Do you have a link / source for that. Because that basically means all webservers that do logging are forbidden.

Comment: @PeeHaa: the IP address is considered private information under certain circumstances and therefor may not be stored without consent of the user. Some usages are OK e.g. when stored in such a way that you cannot link the IP address to a visitor, but still you need to disclose this. Search for "Data Protection Act".

Comment: Thank you, @a_horse_with_no_name ! I wasn't aware of the legal problem, I will look into that! As far as the veracity/reliability of the user agent, I should clarify that I'm asking whether the user agent could reflect a Mac OS X when in fact using a Windows OS WITHOUT setups to change the UA yourself. I'll change my original question to reflect that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A properly functioning browser will transmit a proper user agent for a properly-functioning machine, if that's what you're asking.

If they didn't do something to intentionally change their own user agent (which is very easy- it's one of the first options in the developer menu in Safari on OS X), then the browser should transmit the proper user agent of the machine, if it is working properly.

But that doesn't really help you much, does it?

Comment: No, it does, actually! As far as I know, the person I believed the IP belonged to is using a Windows OS and Firefox/Chrome, so knowing that it's more or less reliable as long as they didn't change the user agent is really helpful, as the person I thought it was honestly probably has no idea what a user agent is in the first place. So I guess I'm back to square one in figuring out their identity, haha. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: That's good, then! Keep in mind though that the "working properly" aspect comes in at that point. But you should be fine: as long as everything _is_ working properly, you're safe in assuming that the unchanged agent is reliable.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if you're a long time reader of SO, but it looks like you're a new member, at least, so the common practice is to accept an answer by clicking the grayed-out check symbol next to an answer. You can find more information about that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If you liked my answer, it would be great if you could accept it so that we both gain [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). Thanks!

Comment: Oh, okay, thank you! Sorry, I didn't see that, I just saw that I couldn't upvote, haha. Thanks for letting me know, I've checked both answers! :)

Comment: You can only accept one answer to a question; it helps later readers who Google this and want a quick answer (doesn't have to be mine, though, as long as you have your answer).

Answer (score 0):

Information about user-agent is a simple string that your system send with request to the server. So there are lot of possibilities to change user-agent manually: from browser addons, to the requests created by-hand.

Comment: I clarified my original question having realized I somehow managed to not specify this, haha, sorry! I was wondering if the user agent can appear to be a Mac OS X when using a Windows OS without altering the user agent yourself purposefully?